# How to make a Calendar in Eclipse with Java by only using loops? (Excluding For loops)

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar

So, basically, I need to make a Calendar by only using loops, and I can not use any `for` loops. I also ask the user for the number of days in the month and what day of the week the first falls on, (0 = Sunday, 3 = Wednesday).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like homework. `What have you tried`?

Comment: Why can't you use `for` loops?  Also, why don't you know how to translate a `for` loop into a `while` loop?